# How can I find the value of inline margin-left using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="ongoing" style="width: +728px; margin-left: +12480px">
```

and I would like to use the value of `margin-left` for scrolling to a position.

I've used the below code to get the value of `width`, but it's not working for `margin-left` (because of the hyphen, I assume?):

```
$("div.ongoing")[0].style.margin-left
```

How can I get the `margin-left` value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
 $("div.ongoing")[0].style.marginLeft
```

or

```
 $("div.ongoing").css("marginLeft");//or .css("margin-left");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
    $('div.ongoing').css('margin-left')